# partial application with Python's os.path.join

Tags: python, functional-programming

I would ideally like to use Python's `functools.partial()` on `os.path.join()`. My use-case looks like:

```py
os.path.join(input_variable_here, "preknown_string")
```

I suppose I could do this by creating a function

```py
def path_join_with_second_known_arg(input):
    return os.path.join(input, "preknown_string")
```

but I'd rather use `partial()`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you think `partial` would be a better fit than a regular function?

Comment: Looking back now, I see it isn't necessarily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
my_path_join = functools.partial(lambda p2, p1: os.path.join(p1, p2), "preknown_string")
```

then use like:

```
my_path_join(input_variable_here)
```